# How to disable the mail health check in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to disable the mail health check in spring boot as the values will be set during runtime. I've found this mentioned in certain GitHub issues for Spring Boot but the configs mentioned vary.

This is my exception after starting my Spring Boot application.

```
  2021-12-13 11:58:52.173 |tion(3)-192.168.1.89 |WARN  |o.s.boot.actuate.mail.MailHealthIndicator   | Mail health check failed
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1
  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2210)
  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:722)
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)
  at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518)
  at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.testConnection(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:398)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.mail.MailHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(MailHealthIndicator.java:42)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:71)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:39)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:99)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:96)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:74)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:61)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:65)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:55)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:77)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:121)
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:96)
  at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
  at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor441.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
  at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:335)
  at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:214)
  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2160)
  ... 48 common frames omitted
```

I've tried adding this to my config but it is throwing the same exception.

```
mail:
  test-connection: false
  properties:
    management:
      health:
        mail:
          enabled: false
```

What is the correct config to disable the mail health checks in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try

```
management:
  health:
    mail:
      enabled: false
```

Answer (score 2):

Add below to the application.properties file present in your resources folder.

```
management.health.mail.enabled=false
```

This answer is just an extension to the accepted answer from Nick.